# TradingView Pinescript, why isn't the ternary operator working in this plot example?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have a very simple strategy in pinescript.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    
...
```

And I'd like to plot a line at value 0 or 1 depending on whether the position size is 0 or not.

```
...
x = strategy.position_size == 0 ? 0 : 1
plot(x)
```

However the result of plotting x is a line that is only at value 1. On the chart
it's clearly displaying that at some points no positions are open. Therefore the
variable `position_size` should be 0 at certain points but it appears its only 1.
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy flip from *long* to *short* and constantly is in a position after the first trade. See the attached screenshot.
[image]

You should use `strategy.exit` or `strategy.close` functions to exit the position before the opposite direction signal occurs.

Example:

```
// Exit long after 2 candles from the entry
exitLong = nz(longCondition[2])
if exitLong
    strategy.close("My Long Entry Id", exitLong)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Can't believe I missed this. Thank you.